# Access to Twitter Account(s)

Tags: ios, twitter

I am using the following code to post to Twitter using SLRequest and ACAccounts in iOS 6.  The issue is that when there is more than one account, I have no control over which one gets access granted.  Suggestions for letting the user pick the account they want to post from?

```
-(void)twitteraccess {
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                                  ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                  completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted == YES)
         {
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                         accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                 NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @"Message"};

                 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL
                                      URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

                 SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                           requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                           requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                           URL:requestURL parameters:message];

                 postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                                          NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"Twitter HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse
                                                           statusCode]);
                  }];
             }
         }
         else {
             if(error.code == 6){
                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(alertmessagetwitter)
                                        withObject:nil
                                     waitUntilDone:YES];                }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Use a UIActionSheet — populated with the accounts in `arrayOfAccounts`.

Comment: @AlanZeino How would I go about making sure that was the only one granted access for future times?  The code I posted is from a settings class the user can turn the access on and off.  In the other class when the action to share is actually called, how do I make it known which account to use?

Comment: I tend to store the account's Identifier in NSUserDefaults — but what if they want to change the default later?

Comment: @AlanZeino I'll update code later for an answer.  I was able to get the account name and present it.  Then, I just wire a button to the same code so they can change it at any time.